# breezejs: collection inconsistencies on client-side

Tags: breeze

I have an entity like this:

```
EntityA {id, someCollectionOfEntityB}
```

I load *entityA* from server with an expand on *someCollectionOfEntityB*.

I have one item in the collection.

Then on the server-side this item is deleted from DB by some third-party application.

Later my client application makes another call to fetch *EntityA* with an expand. This time the expand finds no records and therefore the collection is empty.

Yet, on the client-side, the item that was deleted from DB is still in the collection.

Why ? And how do I change this behaviour ?

**[EDIT]**
I have used the following strategy, but it does not solve the problem:

```
 query.queryOptions = new breeze.QueryOptions({ mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I'm looping through the entities in the collection and I detach each one of them before querying the server again.

I don't think this is a very neat way to solve this issue. So I'd love to hear from the breeze team on this matter :)